# Extrair texto de uma string em python

Tags: python, pandas

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade.
Tenho um df com varias colunas e uma delas é a Descrição. No meio desta descrição tenho o código do produto e gostaria de extrair essa informação para uma nova coluna. Por exemplo

Descrição.: "Esta é a descrição AA-123.456 do produto...."
Nova coluna "AA-123.456"

Alguém sabe como faço isso no python?

Comment: Expressão regular?

Comment: @mercadante tenta especificar melhor a sua pergunta, do jeito que está ninguém vai conseguir ter ajudar. Se puder coloque o código para vermos o que está acontecendo ou o que você precisa. Nessa descrição do seu problema dá a entender que usar expressões regulares ( regex ) vai te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso os códigos tenham um padrão de formação conforme seu exemplo `LL-NNN.NNN`, onde `L` corresponde à uma letra *uppercase* e `N` corresponde à um número. Além disso, tanto o *hífen* quanto o *ponto* aparecem naquela posição específica. Você pode usar o método `str.extract` com a expressão regular `([A-Z]{2}-\d{3}\.\d{3})`

**Nota** Em se tratando de expressões regulares, sempre existe uma mais abrangente.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

### Importando biblioteca

```
import pandas as pd
```

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cod": [1, 2, 3, 4], "descricao": ["Um texto qualquer AA-123.456 e segue com mais coisa", "Outro texto com o codigo BB-232.444 e vamos lá", "Por fim um produto CC-666.888 e fim", "um errado AA-12.3.456"]})

print(df)

   cod                                          descricao
0    1  Um texto qualquer AA-123.456 e segue com mais ...
1    2     Outro texto com o codigo BB-232.444 e vamos lá
2    3                Por fim um produto CC-666.888 e fim
3    4                              um errado AA-12.3.456
```

### Criando nova coluna

```
df["novaColuna"] = df["descricao"].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2}-\d{3}\.\d{3})')

print(df)

   cod                                          descricao  novaColuna
0    1  Um texto qualquer AA-123.456 e segue com mais ...  AA-123.456
1    2     Outro texto com o codigo BB-232.444 e vamos lá  BB-232.444
2    3                Por fim um produto CC-666.888 e fim  CC-666.888
3    4                              um errado AA-12.3.456         NaN
```

Repare que para o último item, não foi extraído o código, pois o mesmo não está no padrão citado.

Comment: Paulo, bom dia! Apliquei sua solução em meu DF e extraiu, porem tenho alguns código que são com 10 digitos outros são 11. Exemplo: SE-XXX-.XXX ou SE-XXX-XXXX  Para os que possuem 11 digitos ele não apresenta o ultimo. Se eu alterar de extract(r'([A-Z]{2}-\d{3}\.\d{3})') para extract(r'([A-Z]{2}-\d{3}\.\d{4})') ai todos os que possuem 10 digitos são apresentados como NaN.

Comment: Paulo, fiz somente este ajuste .str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2}-\d{3}\.\w+)') e funcionou. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Neste caso, o ponto `.` irá pegar **qualquer** caracter ou seja `LL-NNN.NNN `. pegará o espaço no final; ou `LL-NNN.NNNX` pegará o `X`. Use `(r'([A-Z]{2}-\d{3}\.\d{3,4})')`. Assim, pegará 3 ou 4 dígitos no final...